# Placing half border(in the center hidden at the corners) around a div

Tags: html, css

I want to have a border such that it is shown only at the bottom and appears in center only and hidden around the corners:
This is what I have implemented till now :

```css
      .bd{
        border-bottom:1px solid black;
        position: relative;
      }
      .bd:after{
        content: "";
        width:25%;
        height:1.1px;
        background-color:white;
        position: absolute;
        right:0;
        bottom:-1px;
      }
```

```html
<div class="bd">Example</div>
```

What I have been able to achieve with this is I have a border which does not appear at right corner but does appear around left corner and I want to hide it from there as well.
I am not able to achieve that

Comment: Did you try using a "before" in your code? https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/LYrpzmP It's not very nice, it looks a bit hacky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just put the border in as an image (a linear-gradient which just has the middle bit as black).

```css
.bd {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 0 25%, black 25% 75%, transparent 75% 100%) 1 / 0 0 1px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="bd">Example</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a gradient for the line:

```css
h3 {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .line {
       height: 2px;
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right, white , black, white);
    }
h4 {
    border-bottom: 2px solid;
    border-image-slice: 1;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-image-source: linear-gradient(to left, #fff, #000, #fff);
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h3>Heading</h3>   
<div class="line"></div>
<h4>Heading</h4>
```

Comment: Seems good but to be consistent with my other components I need a simple line as border

Comment: Seemsa bit OTT to have to add an element into the DOM just to have a border which is really a visual clue rather than having any great meaning contentwise.

Comment: I prefer the clarity of this solution. Why would changing your HTML be any different from changing the CSS? Unless of course your HTML code is a bit a mess.

Comment: @AHaworth: HTML can be used for both: semantic content and visual clues.

Comment: I've updated the sample above, please see H4.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a pseudo box that is the same height as its real counterpart, but is less wide with some absolute positioning (but the base of the positioning is the original element).

```css
h4 { position: relative; }

h4:before {
  /* change these to change the size of the border */
  left: 25%;
  right: 25%;
  
  /* change this to change the border itself */
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  
  /* */
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<h4>Text</h4>
```